# OS X / iOS: How do I create a PDF that can't get printed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, encryption, cgpdfcontext

I want to create a PDF document, that can't get printed. I am using the Quartz framework for that. This is what I do (shorted):

```
    PDFDocument *pdfDocument = ...

    NSMutableDictionary *options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [options setValue:@"test-password" forKey:(NSString *)kCGPDFContextUserPassword];
    [options setValue:@0 forKey:(NSString *)kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting];

    [pdfDocument writeToFile:savePath withOptions:options];
```

But I can still print the resulting file with Preview.app without having to type in a password.

If I set a *kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword*, the document is locked with the password (but not the print function)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

[CGPDFContext Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using *CFMutableDictionaryRef* instead of *NSMutableDictionary*, it finally works. Don't ask me why... :D

Answer (score 0):

Set `kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting` value to `kCFBooleanFalse` but by The `default` value of this key is `kCFBooleanTrue`.

Whether the document allows printing when unlocked with the user password.